# How to configure the HiDPI mode after updating IntelliJ to 2017.2.6?

Tags: intellij-idea

After updating IntelliJ to 2017.2.6, how could I configure the HiDPI mode?

[image: screenshot]

I had read the [passage](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001260010) online.

But I am sorry that I still don't know how to configure.

I need your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you specify please what exactly is not clear? The article describes different solutions one may try if IDE appearance is not satisfactory for you (bad DPI scaling). E.g. set DPI mode to be managed by IDE via the `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false` .vmoption.

Comment: I find that I don't have to configure anything because if I try to configure like this [one](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000556364-IntelliJ-magnifies-after-computer-sleeps?page=1#community_comment_115000479810), there would be some display problem on the IntelliJ IDEA. If I don't do anything, it'll be fine. So now I just choose "Do not show again" to eliminate this warning. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now there is a new version, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4..